# Нужен ли дефис?

Tags: орфография

Нужен ли дефис в слове email?

Answer (score 1):

С марта 2011 года англоязычным СМИ рекомендуется писать сокращение от «электронная почта» как «email», а не «e-mail», но в русском языке присутствует значительная вариативность. Наиболее часто в кириллических текстах также используется «e-mail»

http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Так и не понял, кем рекомендовано.

Comment: Орфографической комиссией, видимо, или как она там называется в этих странах.

Comment: Значит  для  нас  в  любом  случае  ошибки  не  будет ?

Answer (score 0):

Раз существует вариативность, ошибки не будет.